# rxdart BehaviorSubject transaction

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, reactive-programming, bloc

In firebase, we can do transaction like this

```dart
final dataRef = database.reference().child('path/to/data');

dataRef.runTransaction((MutableData transaction) async{
    transaction.value = (transaction.value ?? 0) + 1;
    return transaction;
});
```

I wonder we can have the same with BehaviorSubject; something like this

```dart
final subject = new BehaviorSubject<int>();

subject.add(1);
subject.add(2);
subject.add(3);
subject.runTransaction((int currentData) => currentData + 2);
// or 
subject.add(subject.value + 2);

subject.stream.listen(print); // prints 7
subject.stream.listen(print); // prints 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look, and it seems we can currently achieve this.

1. Firstly, "Once a Dart function starts executing, it continues executing until it exits. In other words, Dart functions can’t be interrupted by other Dart code.", [ref](https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop#darts-single-thread-of-execution) (except, and it's a big *EXCEPT* `await` key word, even though technically using `await` is already interrupt and return the code in the `Future`)
2. Secondly, looking at [RxDart source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/blob/master/lib/src/subjects/behavior_subject.dart#L126), both `add` and `setter` are synchronous (no `Future`, no `await`), so the following code is simple and guarantee to works as a transaction:

```dart
subject.add(subject.value + 2);
```